# How to get to Mythbusters' duct tape island

Tags: islands, identify-this, hawaii

After watching the [Duct tape island](http://dsc.discovery.com/fansites/mythbusters/photogalleries/duct-tape-island/pictures-02.html) episode of the MythBusters show I was totally in love with that uninhabited island. They say it is in Hawaii but no more details.

[image: duct tape island]

[image]

**Whats the name of that island? if it has one!**
**Is there a way to actually get to it and spend a night or two there?**

Comment: The two mythbusters did admit they weren't in a stranded island. I forgot where they said they did shoot it but they did admit they had easy access to civilization, and didn't "play" fair

Comment: The first question of the Myth Buster's [Duct Tape Island Aftershow](http://www.discovery.com/tv-shows/mythbusters/videos/duct-tape-island-aftershow.htm) is the 'where is this island'. Same location as LOST (the had to avoid getting the hotel in the shots).

Comment: Heh. An uninhabited island, shown in a TV show? You and a half a billion others will soon be leaving your trash behind....

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I called [IMDB](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt2307725/) to the rescue.  The filming location is: [Turtle Bay, O'ahu, Hawaii, USA](http://maps.google.nl/maps?q=Turtle%20Bay,%20O%27ahu,%20Hawaii,%20USA&hl=nl&sll=51.26448,5.896434&sspn=0.934946,2.469177&hnear=Turtle%20Bay&t=m&z=15)

The photo you have uploaded can be [bought](http://www.oceanfootage.com/stockfootage/Coral_Reef_Australia_Aerial) It appears to be Green Island in Australia.

I did find the location of island mentioned in the question through [google image search](http://www.google.be/imghp?hl=en&tab=wi). To this relatively new feature of google search enables to locate a picture. This can be done by dragging any picture to the search field of google (which then changes in a dropbox). This picture itself is then the "keyword".

The approach is not water tight, but in this case it was possible to identify green island.

Comment: so they lied? it is not stranded island in the middle of the ocean?

Comment: @HaLaBi - To be fair, I don't recall them ever saying they were actually on a deserted island, some of it was fairly tongue in cheek (i.e. raw steak and fried chicken for dinner).

Comment: @RobZ I am sure they said so (or something similar). I will watch it again and tell you the exact time.

Comment: @MeNoTalk did you re-watch?

Comment: @MarkMayo do I really have to? it is been 30 years already ;)

Comment: You said you were going to, we're waiting patiently :D

Comment: @MarkMayo ok, patience is good, keep waiting.. I'll rewatch it and let you know

Comment: @MarkMayo watch [the episode](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=q408iAWHnXU), go to 00:00:10 (tenth second) and they will clearly say "deserted island"... that's the proof!

Comment: @rob too, read the comment above.

Comment: The link takes us to a broken video page?

Comment: But wait, are there boars? @NeanDerThal

Answer (score 16):

From the files of "don't believe everything you see on TV (especially on Mythbusters)", we have...

The Island that you've included the photo for is "[Green Island](https://maps.google.com/maps?ll=-16.760043,145.971608&z=15)", and is located just off Cairns in Australia.  It is most certainly not an 'uninhabited island", and even has a [Resort](http://www.greenislandresort.com.au/) you can stay at for only $600+ per night!

Fairly clearly that Island isn't where Mythbusters actually filmed the show.  In fact, the footage of the island from above is simply [file footage](http://www.oceanfootage.com/video_clips/JB05_071)

Comment: well, I feel naive now ;)

Comment: I guess most of us do now

Comment: There's two photos. I was confused until I just figured out what you meant.

Answer (score 2):

They reran this episode tonight.  If I saw it correctly, Turtle Bay Resort in Hawaii was listed in the credits at the end of the show.  That would seem to agree with the answer above.