# How to get to "Life Of Pi's" bizarre island?

Tags: where-on-earth, islands

I am always fascinated by islands, especially the uninhabited or bizarre ones. I also previously asked about [The duct tape island of Mythbusters](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/9263/how-to-get-to-mythbusters-duct-tape-island).

My new pursuit of interest is the bizarre island from the movie [Life of Pi](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0454876/?ref_=nv_sr_2). Where is it located and how to get to it? (if it is real).

[image: life of pi]

Comment: Lie of Pie eh? Interesting...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

While the island in the book/movie is clearly imaginary, similar floating vegetative islands can and do exist.

As explained on [Could the floating islands of "Life of Pi" really exist?](http://www.straightdope.com/columns/read/2709/could-the-floating-islands-of-life-of-pi-really-exist), some exist in various parts of the world that have vegetation and sometimes even animals (dancing deer on an Indian island).

Indeed, I've been to the floating Uros islands in Lake Titica, Peru, which are, however, man-made, but have people living on them.

But an acidic, carnivorous island with teeth in the fruit of the plants it bears? Nope :)

Comment: Dubai? Palm Jumeiraa, World Islands

Comment: @AdityaSomani yes, but also not acidic, or carnivorous ;)

Comment: @AdityaSomani and it doesn't float. Rather it sinks...

Comment: @jwenting What doesn't float? World islands and all?

Comment: @AdityaSomani yes, the world islands. They're build of rock and sand dumped on the sea floor until they break through the surface, then clad with more rock and sand. And it's subsiding.